# Unite columns of dataframe by using wildcards in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to unite columns of a csv file, that have similar naming patterns. Some files have columns matching that pattern, but it is not known, how many there are.

Consider following example code:

```
df <- unite(df, "united", "name.x", "name.y", "name.xyz", sep="_")
```

I would like to make use of the `select()` function, but don't know how.

For example, I had this idea

```
 df <- unite(df, select(df, contains("name")), sep="_")
```

but unfortunately it gets me an error:

```
...must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `select` verb. Just do this

```r
unite(df, contains("name"), sep = "_")
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I wish at some point docus were written ELI5 style. Because the line: "For more options, see the dplyr::select() documentation. " left me desperate.

Comment: I guess the reason is that's where you can find out how to use the select helper functions including `contains`.

Comment: I just didn't grasp that you can use inside the argument, without calling "select()" itself.

Answer (score 0):

The same as above. But I believe you got to give it a new column name:

```
unite(df, "New_column_name", contains("name"), sep = "_")
```